# Cannot extract event.target.value from an onClick event on a <span> element

Tags: reactjs

I have a simple context sub-menu in a data tree which allows to perform view/add/delete actions on a tree node.

[image]

The menu items are <span> elements with onClick events attached to them like so:

```
<div>
  <span onClick={handleConfirmation} value="modify">Modify</span>
  <span onClick={handleConfirmation} value="view">View</span>
  <span onClick={handleConfirmation} value="add">Add</span>
  <span onClick={handleConfirmation} value="delete">Delete</span>
</div>
```

The onClick is supposed to trigger a modal window that shows dynamic content depending on which span was clicked. The idea is to get the value of the "value" attribute from the event.target and send it to the modal so it can show different content depending on that value.

When I click on for example the "Delete" span, the event does fire, but I am getting "undefined" from event.target.value in my callback handler:

```
function handleConfirmation(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const value = event.target.value;
    console.log(value);
};
```

and the console logs event.target as the span itself like this

```
<span value="delete">Delete</span>
```

I also get "undefined" from event.***currentTarget***.value.

If I change the spans to be button tags, then the event.target.value returns the button's value as expected.

I know I cannot attach events to custom components, but I thought I could do that for any valid DOM elements, which a span is. Why is it not possible to extract attributes from the event when I attach it to a span tag?

Comment: can you try event.currentTarget.value ?

Comment: I have tried that. Doesn't work either. Same thing (the span itself) in console.log()

Comment: An aside  - for accessibility reasons you shouldn't put an `onClick` on a span.  Use a `button` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Tested for myself, `spanElement.value` is also giving undefined.

But I got round it with the `getAttribute()` method instead.

```
function handleConfirmation(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const value = event.target.getAttribute("value");
    console.log(value);
};
```